# Adding user manually without sign-up on Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to create an Android app connected to Firebase Using it's Authentication ... The thing is I don't want to add sign-up/register feature since it's been used by only one person. Just a single user login for that can I add user manually from Firebase console to my project app if so how to connect and authentic it?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to manually add a user is to enable email/password sign in, then use the Firebase console to create that account using your specified email and password data.  You can't use the console to create other types of accounts (such as Google or Facebook, since those accounts must be validated by those providers directly).

Comment: yea i don't want google n facebook .Added user manually in firebase now how to connect it to the app so that it only takes the given mail n pass ? do i have to add any extra firebase libraries in my android studio?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Just sign in the user with the email and password you chose